# WTS LastInputTime

Tags: c++, winapi, wtsapi32

i'm trying to retrive the difference between CurrentTime and LastInputTime and comparing it to another value. CurrentTime is updating correctly but LastInputTime is always a constant value, i dont know why sometimes is 0 , sometimes is other constant value . Any help ?

```
void localSessions()
{
    while (TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Risky local logon sessions :" << endl;
        DWORD pCount;
        PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessionsInfo=new WTS_SESSION_INFO[MAX_SESSIONS];
        WTSEnumerateSessionsA(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionsInfo, &pCount);
        DWORD bytes;
        for (auto it = 0; it < pCount; it++)
        {
            WTSINFOEX* ptr;
            if (pSessionsInfo[it].State == WTSActive)
            {
                INT ret = WTSQuerySessionInformationA(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, pSessionsInfo[it].SessionId, WTSSessionInfoEx, (LPSTR*)&ptr, &bytes);
                if (ret != 0)
                {
                    INT ret = Gambit::OS::Environment::GetOSVersion();
                    INT unlocked = 0, unknown = 0;
                    LONGLONG last_input = ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.CurrentTime.QuadPart - ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.LastInputTime.QuadPart;
                    cout << last_input << endl;
                    HANDLE token;
                    WTSQueryUserToken(pSessionsInfo[it].SessionId, &token);
                    ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token);
                    BOOL active;
                    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &active, 0);
                    RevertToSelf();
                    if (!(ret >= 16 && ret <= 19))
                    {
                        if ((ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.SessionFlags & WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNLOCK) != 0)
                        {
                            unlocked = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (ret >= 16 && ret <= 19)
                    {
                        if ((ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.SessionFlags & WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK) != 0)
                        {
                            unlocked = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (unlocked == 1 && active == FALSE && last_input > 500000000000)
                    {
                        cout << "Winstation name : " << ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.WinStationName << endl;
                        cout << "UserName name : " << ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.UserName << endl;
                        cout << "Domain name : " << ptr->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.DomainName << endl;
                    }

                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you are leaking the array you allocate, and worse you are leaking memory that both `WTSEnumerateSessionsA()` and `WTSQuerySessionInformationA()` are allocating and returning to you. You need to call `WTSFreeMemory()` when you are done using the returned memory. You are not supposed to allocate the `WTS_SESSION_INFO` array yourself, `WTSEnumerateSessionsA()` allocates it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LastInputTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wtsinfoex_level1_a) is zero for a **local session**.

For a **remote session**, when there is no user input after last query of `LastInputTime`, it will keep unchanged. If there is a user input (like mouse move etc), `LastInputTime` will update to new time.

If you want to monitor local session user input time you can use [`GetLastInputInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) instead.